# Does Godel's completeness theorem stands for formulas which are not sentences?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Godel completeness theorem (as I am familiar with): $\Sigma\models \alpha \Rightarrow \Sigma\vdash \alpha$.
In class (A year ago) we proved the next claim: $\Sigma$ is **Theory** - a set of **sentences** - is consistent $\Rightarrow$ $\Sigma$ has a model, 
And proved:  the last claim $\Rightarrow$ Godel completeness theorem.

My question is , does the completeness theorem stands for **formulas which are not sentences?**

I was also searching in  Mendelson's and Enderton's books, but they demonstrate the prove in slightly different way than the lecturer did ,and I am not sure whether I fully understood it.

Comment: @EricWofsey , may you please explain why so? as I understand model's definition for $\Sigma$ is a structure $M$ for language $L$ such that $M\models \alpha , \forall \alpha \in \Sigma$

Comment: See also the post : [true-or-falsehood-of-open-formula-under-a-fixed-interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837162/true-or-falsehood-of-open-formula-under-a-fixed-interpretation).

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry, I miss-typed and I believe you had read it before I got to edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see [Enderton](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA135), page 135 :

> **COMPLETENESS THEOREM (Gödel, 1930)**
>
> > (b) Any consistent set of *formulas* is satisfiable

provided that the semantical relation $\vDash$ of *satisfaction* in an interpretation is defined for formulas: see [page 83](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA83).

But there is a different approach: see Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA67), Springer (5th ed. 2013), page 67) where the definition of meaning and truth value is limited to *sentences*, i.e. "closed" formulas.

In this case, the following convention is adopted:

> $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi$  **iff** $\mathfrak A \vDash \text{Cl}(\varphi)$,

where $\text{Cl}(\varphi)$ is the *universal closure* of $\varphi$.

Having said that, we have that $\Gamma \vDash \psi \text { iff (if } \mathfrak A \vDash \Gamma \text {, then } \mathfrak A \vDash \psi)$, where $\Gamma$ and $\psi$ are *sentences*.

---

As pointed by Carl Mummert, the two conventions disagree about satisfiability, also if they agree about validity : under both approaches the formula $x ≠ y$ is not valid.

In a nutshell, Enderton's approach adopts as basic the *satisfaction* relation (following Tarski) while van Dalen's one adopts as basic the *true (in a model)* relation.

Comment: This is a very important distinction, because for example $x \not = y$ is satisfiable under Enderton's convention but not under van Dalen's convention.